# Executing stored procedure calls create procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have what I think is a fairly simple stored procedure in SQL Server 2017. It basically just deletes some data from three tables and does that within a transaction.

I have drop/create scripts for this sproc that run as part of the seeding in Entity Framework. That's the only place that create procedure exists and according to logging statements, it only seems to execute once on deployment as expected.

Here's the problem... occasionally I end up with some serious performance issues and they seem linked to database performance. When I look at my application log, I see that this stored procedure is being executed. But when I look at currently executing queries, it's trying to run a create procedure query for this stored procedure.

I'm using the following query to see the running queries:

```
SELECT 
    sqltext.TEXT, req.session_id, req.status, 
    req.command, req.cpu_time, req.total_elapsed_time 
FROM 
    sys.dm_exec_requests req 
CROSS APPLY 
    sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) AS sqltext
```

I have quite a bit of experience with SQL Server, but not so much with stored procedures and I can't seem to find any documentation that suggests a create procedure query should be running as part of executing a stored procedure.

Is it weird that create procedure gets run? Or is that normal when executing a stored procedure?

Comment: That's normal. You'll see the same thing if you look at `SELECT sm.definition FROM sys.sql_modules sm;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is normal. If you want to see a particular statement which is being executed, you need to use `statement_start_offset` and `statement_end_offset` from `sys.dm_exec_requests`:

```
SELECT 
CASE   
        WHEN req.[statement_start_offset] > 0 THEN  
            CASE req.[statement_end_offset]  
               WHEN -1 THEN  
                  SUBSTRING(sqltext.TEXT, (req.[statement_start_offset]/2) + 1, 2147483647) 
               ELSE   
                  SUBSTRING(sqltext.TEXT, (req.[statement_start_offset]/2) + 1, (req.[statement_end_offset] - req.[statement_start_offset])/2+1)   
            END  
        ELSE  
            CASE req.[statement_end_offset]  
               WHEN -1 THEN  
                  RTRIM(LTRIM(sqltext.[text]))  
               ELSE  
                  LEFT(sqltext.TEXT, (req.[statement_end_offset]/2) +1)  
            END  
        END AS [executing statement],
    sqltext.TEXT, req.session_id, req.status, 
    req.command, req.cpu_time, req.total_elapsed_time 
FROM 
    sys.dm_exec_requests req 
CROSS APPLY 
    sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) AS sqltext
```

Comment: I guess that explains it. Glad to know I'm not going crazy.

Answer (score 1):

This explains the issue a bit more:

> sys.dm_exec_sql_text DMF will return only Text of the SQL query not
> the execution query text along with other details(dbid, objectid etc).
>
> If you are executing adhoc, you will see the execution statement. But
> for proc it will shoe the text of proc not the execution statement.

If you want to get the currently executing portion:

```
SELECT  r.session_id ,
    OBJECT_NAME(qt.objectid, qt.dbid) AS [Stored procedure name],
    SUBSTRING(qt.[text], r.statement_start_offset / 2,
        ( CASE WHEN r.statement_end_offset = -1
               THEN LEN(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), qt.[text])) * 2
               ELSE r.statement_end_offset
          END - r.statement_start_offset ) / 2) AS [statement_executing] 
FROM    sys.dm_exec_requests AS r
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) AS qt
WHERE   r.session_id > 50
```

Found it in the [MSDN forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f9921d83-e262-4688-ae78-35d2588cab6a/why-is-the-sql-text-is-create-procedure-sptest-when-i-am-executing-procedure-sptest-)